# OnTextChanged not called when edittext length is full

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have scenario where I allow only 1 character in edittext. so in onTextChanged I have checked if one letter is input, then I switch the focus to next edittext

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/etpinPassword1"
                style="@style/Edittext_with_weight"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1" />
```

and here my is textWatcher code:

onTextChanged :- >

```
if (isValueEntered(charSequence)) {
                    etpinPassword2.requestFocus();
                    etpinPassword2.setEnabled(true);
                    appendPassword(charSequence);
                }

private boolean isValueEntered(CharSequence charSequence) {
        return charSequence.length() > 0;
    }
```

Everything is working fine, except when I come back to an already filled edittext, onTextChanged is never called. I want to call it again so that I can switch the focus to next edittext if first one is already full.

Comment: you are removing the text on your second visit to filled edittext ?

Comment: How are you going back to the filled EditText? Check that it regains focus. Also the method won't be called if you don't change the text

Comment: put your operation in after text changed listener.

Comment: @RED_ I am manually clicking my edittext back again, to check negative cases

Comment: @rajanks No I m not removing my text, I am just trying to enter another text and want that on more text input it should move to other edittext as current one is already full

Comment: See my solution for pin-code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464357/2914140.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set the max length to 1, so it will prevent you by entering other character.

Comment: How can I do both things, I want  to set maxLength as 1 and also want to check if a user is typing after 1 digit is entered

Comment: why would user type another character without removing one ?

Comment: I want to handle it, that if already typed and user is still typing it should move to another edittext. Actually I am making a four digit pin view, where I have four edittext with maxLength as 1 for each edittext.